# What is the minimum number of tossing needed to get at least 1 sequential 5 heads? Fair Coin

Tags: probability

I know that the probability of getting 5 heads in a row while tossing a fair coin is `1/32` which is `1/(2^5)`. Now I want to reverse the question: **what is the minimum number of tossing needed to get at least 1 sequential 5 heads?**

Since the previous probability was 1 out of 32, can I say that if I toss the coin 32 times, I will be **sure and certain** that I will get at least 5 head in a row once?  If it's not **sure**, what is the probability of this uncertainty?

Comment: There is no such number. If your coin is completely random you could get an infinite sequence with no 5 sequential heads.

Comment: @Wauzl so what does P=1/32 actually mean?

Comment: It means that if we do the procedure "flip a coin 5 times" we will get "only heads" with a probability of 1/32, see answer of @florence.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how many times you flip the coin, there will always be a nonzero probability that you do not get five heads in a row. If you flip the coin $n$ times, for instance, there is a probability of $2^{-n}$ that you will only gets tails. So, we can say that the probability of getting five heads in a row is always less than or equal to $1-2^{-n}$, which is always less than $1$.

When we say that the probability of getting five heads in a row when flipping the coin five times is $\frac{1}{32}$, this can be interpreted as saying that if you perform this process many times, then you'll get five heads in a in row about $\frac{1}{32}$ of the trials.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the probability of 100 tails in a row: $1 / 2^{100}$ which is a a very small but not zero number.  Now a million tails in a row: $1 / 2^{1000000}$ which is very, very small but still not zero.  Similarly for even bigger numbers.  So, you are not even guaranteed to get a single head however many times that you toss the coin.

If you change the question to include something like "beyond reasonable doubt" then you could get an answer but you would have to define what that meant.  Does it mean less than one in a million chance of being wrong?  One in a billion, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There's a minor distinction I'd like to make. You *can* actually be certain that you will get five heads if you sample an *infinite* number of flips, and you'll always reach five heads within *some* finite number of flips. You just can't place an upper bound on how many flips that will take.

Mathematically, as you approach $\omega$ flips, the probability of any possible sequence (or count) of flips, no matter how remote, approaches $1$. You can be certain you'll hit five heads after some finite ($<\omega$) number of trials because the probability you won't get there *eventually* is precisely $0$.